# Why are 1990-4-1 2:00 and 1990-4-1 3:00 the same date (JS + SQL)

Tags: javascript, sql, formatting

Does anyone know why 1990-4-1 2:00 and 1990-4-1 3:00 are the same date using JS (new Date)? This also causes an issue in SQL if that date is a key.

[image]

Comment: how can you be sure in this date format? "4/1/90" why is it 1990 year ?

Comment: *"... if that date is a key."* sounds like a serious design flaw regardless the issue at hand.

Comment: Although it may work for some dates, that date/time format is not in any format that is guaranteed by the specification, which means A) It may not be parsed correctly, and B) even if it is, you can't be sure whether it's parsed as UTC or local time. Use the [specified format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format), or the multi-argument `Date` constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Clocks jumped ahead by an hour at 2am that day in some Daylight Savings areas.

Comment: Including in the time zone of the OP (their profile says New York, USA): https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=1990 Or put another way, there **was** no 2:00 a.m. on the first of April 1990 in New York's timezone.